# Saving data to the firebase database

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase and saving data to it. I am reading these docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data
 but I am getting confused as how to use the `curl` command.

I have a .json file and I also have this javascript file with the following method in:

```
submitToDB.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if(document.getElementById('Hannah').checked){
        liked.set(Hannah.value)
        console.log('checked')
      } else {
        console.log('not checked')
      }
    });
```

Json file:

```
{
  "users": {
    "alanisawesome": {
      "date_of_birth": "June 23, 1912",
      "full_name": "Alan Turing"
    }
  }
}
```

This will check if the Hannah checkbox is liked but then add it to the database. However, I cant work out from the docs how to add large amounts of JSON and how to turn the user inputted into JSON and then submit in the form I want.

If unclear can answer any questions.

Comment: Why are you trying to use curl? Firebase has a web SDK that is way easier to get started with. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start. Writing a value is covered [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data#basic_write).

Answer (score 0):

Hey the curl can be confusing if you never used it before. Regardless, here is a solution that I use in typescript but it should work with javascript as well.

Assuming you have:

```
export class SubmitData {
      _listPath:FirebaseListObservable<any>;
      constructor(firebase:Firebase) {
          const path = `/users/`;
          //pass the path here
          this._listPath = _firebase.database.list(path);
      }

 submitData() {
    //Magic happens here. This works. Test it with my test app.
    //Array object. Creates a user or users
    let data = [
          {
            alanisawesome: "Genius",
            date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
            full_name: "Alan Turing"
          },
          {
            fathersofSilicon: "Silicon Icon",
            date_of_birth: "October 13, 1956",
            full_name: "Marc Regis Hannah"
          }

       ]
     //This is how the push method works.
     return this._listPath.push(data); 

    } 
  }
```

Comment: Th easiest way to submit data is to use the version of array object I have created. That will get you up and running quickly as you discover how you want to really format your data in firebase. Look into structure your firebase data.